# Blazor Server (.net 8) Dynamic Image Rendering only happening at the end of processing

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor Server App (.Net 9) . Interactive Server Render mode is enabled in program.cs.

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
   .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

I have an file upload progress bar which works flawlessly. The issue is when trying to dynamically show processed images within an `<img>`

The application processes images in bullk, so when each image is processed- the preview should be displayed to the user. But in my case the image is refreshed only when the whole processing completes.

This is how the image is processed

```
private async Task ProcessImages()
{

    Bitmap processedimage = null;
    foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
    {

        using (var img = Bitmap.FromFile(file))
        {
            processedimage = imageservice.Process((Bitmap)img);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(processedimage ))
                {
                    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ImageUri = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())}";
                    StateHasChanged();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Image is set like this

```
`<img src=@ImageUri asp-append-version="true" width="190px" style="float: none; text-align: left; border-radius: 10px; border: 2px dotted #0332ff; padding: 40px" /`>
```

Comment: What if you give it time to render by uding a `Task. Yield()` after StateHasChanged?

Comment: OT I don't think asp-append-version works in Blazor. And why are you saving as jpg but then claiming it's png?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Task.Yield() does not make any difference, The JPEG format is a typo.. will correct.

Comment: Try `await Task.Delay(1)` before statehaschanged and you can also use the asynchronous `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task ProcessImages()
{
    foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
    {
       //
    
      StateHasChanged();
      await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Introduce `await Task.Yield()` within the image processing loop to allow Blazor's UI thread to update after processing each image.